Torrent created a corrupted folder that links back to the download folder
I recently torrented (using qbittorrent) an anime from a website I consider reputable (not going to link it here as I don't know if it's against TOS) from a supplier that is flagged as reputable on the site itself. However, when the file finished installing, it created a new nameless file as seen in the following image:

Furthermore looking at the properties of the folder, it says that it contains 0 bytes of information and it has no creation or modification date and when I open it I only get sent to the download folder again.
Opening it a second time leads me to the actual torrent, however when I try to open that it gives me an error message saying "Your input can't be opened:

VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///C:/Users/[USER]/Downloads/%20/%20/[FILENAME].mkv'. Check the log for details.

Trying to do anything with the folder like moving it, renaming it or deleting it only throws the error:

The action cannot be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program

And deleting the torrented file throws the error:

Could not find this item; This is no longer located in C:\Users[USER]\Downloads\ . Verify the item's location and try again.

The only thing that might have happen differently during the download (that I don't know for sure happened with exactly this file) is that I erased the download path and pressed esc/ctrl+z.

The folder name ends with a space, and although Windows allows spaces at the end of path components it does not allow spaces at the end of the entire path. For example, Downloads\blah \blah is valid but Downloads\blah  alone will get the space automatically removed.
In your case, the .torrent likely had a folder with just one space character in its name, and the BitTorrent software used Downloads\ \ as the path (or possibly some other ways that also exist in Win32) to create it, but other programs that blindly use Downloads\  (one space at the end) end up accessing just the parent Downloads directory itself.
Try using qBitTorrent to rename the downloaded file through its "Torrent contents" list. If that doesn't work, open Cmd and try deleting it from there:
rd/s "Downloads\ \"

